# Как добавить правило (udev/rules), при подключении планшета HUION в linux?

Tags: linux, archlinux, rules, udev

При подключении графического планшета **HUION 640p** через **usb**, хочу запускать скрипт в **rules**:

/etc/udev/rules.d/tablet.rules

```
ACTION=="add",
SYBSYSTEM=="input",
KERNEL=="mouse",
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x256c",
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x006d",
RUN+="/usr/bin/huion"
```

**huion** скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d stylus" Rotate half # Left handed orientation
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d Pad pad" button 1 key Delete
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d Pad pad" button 2 key Shift
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d Pad pad" button 3 key E
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d Pad pad" button 8 key Ctrl
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d Pad pad" button 9 key B
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d Pad pad" button 10 key Ctrl Z
```

вывод xsetwacom list

```
HID 256c:006d stylus                id: 14  type: STYLUS
HID 256c:006d Touch Strip pad       id: 15  type: PAD
HID 256c:006d Pad pad               id: 16  type: PAD
```

Вывод lsusb -v:

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 256c:006d
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x256c
  idProduct          0x006d
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           5
  iProduct                6
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x003b
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      18
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               2
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      93
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               2
```

Но ничего не работает( Поможет кто?

Comment: не работает потому что `xsetwacom` должен запускаться в контексте сессии X-ов, а удав о них ничего не знает... для протокола: при ручном запуске скрипт конфигурирует всё правильно? ИМХО правильным решением было бы записать всё это в конфиг X'ов. см. [вику арча](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wacom_tablet),  [`man 4 wacom`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/wacom) и [вику xf86-input-wacom](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/xorg.conf.d). кнопки, судя по всему, придётся замапить на старшие кнопки мыши, и только потом на клавиши клавиатуры...

Comment: при использовании скрипта из терминала все прекрасно работает. Я также добавил эти команды в автозапуск i3. Если планшет полючен во время запуска ос всё работает. Но если переподлючу - настройки падают.

Comment: в качестве очень грязного хака можно дописать в начало `export DISPLAY=:0` и, может быть, в `xprofile` `xhost +:local`... но, как говорил выше, я бы всё же прописал бы всё это в конфиг иксов...

Comment: Проблема в том, что не знаю как прописывать этот конфиг. Беру конфиг с **https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers**, прописываю свой id устройсва, но и для примера пишу `Option "Button1" "Delete"` то ничего не работает.

Comment: да, иксовый конфиг не поддерживает сопоставление кнопок планшета клавишам клавиатуры... в арчевой вике предлагают замапить их на старшие кнопки мыши (`Option "Button1" 11`), а затем с помощью `xbindkeys` и `xdotool` привязать их к клавишам клавиатуры (`"xdotool key Delete"   \n   b:11` в `~/.xbindkeysrc`)... ЗЫ: прописывать «свои» идентификаторы (`MatchUSBID` или `MatchDevicePath`) устройства, скорее всего, __не__ нужно и достаточно будет общих `MatchDriver "wacom"` // `MatchProduct "pad"`.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо тебе! Ура! Теперь перечитывая доку арча вижу как это делать!